# Subtracting sets in Python3 and getting output in list format

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-structures, syntax-error

I have 2 sets:

```
A = [2,2,2,3,5,4]
B = [2]
```

I want to remove all 2's from `A`. I am doing this by subtracting `B` from `A`, and I need the output in a list format.
So, I did  the following:

```
y = list(set(A) - set(B))
```

However, it says:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

If I use `y = list[set(CLI) - set(x)]`, it says:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not set
```

Any suggestions, how I could get the output in the list format?

Comment: It seems you have used `list` as variable somewhere and shadowed the builtin `list` with that.

Comment: You do not have sets it is list. In set() all items are unique and declaired with {} not [].

Answer (score 1):

This could also work.

```
a = [2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4]
b = [2]
def subtract_lists(a, b):
    for i in b:
        while i in a:
            a.remove(i)
    return a
print (subtract_lists(a, b))
```

Output
[3, 5, 4]

Comment: Variable `c` is unnecessary

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally overlooked that @MichaelButscher

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on my computer:

```
A = [2,2,2,3,5,4] 
B = [2]
y = list(set(A) - set(B))
print(y)
```

Output:

```
[3, 4, 5]
```